# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined (array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know, this is probably the most asked error about JavaScipt! But I've read, at least 20 articles about this error on StackOverflow and none gave me the information that I needed. So, sorry in advance for any stupid question! ;)

I am starting a basic battleship game with JavaScript. For now, I have two functions: boats (generates boats) and table (generates table and interacts with the user. These are the complete functions:

Table:

```
function table (){
     const DIM = parseInt(prompt("Insert the size:"));
     var arr = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < DIM; i++){
         arr[i] = [];
         for (var j = 0; j < DIM; j++){
             arr[i][j] = parseInt(0);
         }
     }
     arr = boats(5, 1, DIM, arr); //1 Carrier
     arr = boats(4, 1, DIM, arr); //1 Battleship
     arr = boats(3, 2, DIM, arr); //2 Cruiser
     arr = boats(2, 3, DIM, arr); //3 Destroyer
     arr = boats(1, 4, DIM, arr); //4 Submarines
     console.log(arr);
}
```

Boats:

```
function boats (siz, numb,  DIM, arr){
    console.log(arr);
    var size = siz;
    var nrboats = numb;
    var step = 0;
    while (step < nrboats) {
        var random_column = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random() * DIM)));
        console.log(random_column);
        var random_line = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random() * DIM)));
        console.log(random_line);
        var verification = true;
        var orientation = "";
        while (verification && orientation === "") {
            for(var k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                if (arr[random_line][Math.min((random_column) + k, DIM-1)] === 0 && arr[random_line][((random_column) + 1 + k)] === 0 && arr[random_line][((random_column) - 1 + k)] === 0 && arr[((random_line) + 1)][(random_column + k)] === 0 && arr[((random_line) - 1)][(random_column + k)] === 0) {
                     verification = true;
                     orientation = "horizontal";
                 } else if (arr[Math.min((random_line) + k,DIM-1)][random_column] === 0 && arr[((random_line) + k)][((random_column) + 1)] === 0 && arr[((random_line) + k)][((random_column) - 1)] === 0 && arr[((random_line) + 1 + k)][random_column] === 0 && arr[((random_line) - 1 + k)][random_column] === 0) {
                     verification = true;
                     orientation = "vertical";
                 } else {
                     verification = false;
                 }
        }
        if (verification && orientation === "horizontal") {
            for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){
                arr[random_line][random_column+i] = 1;
            }
            step++;
        } else if (verification && orientation === "vertical") {
            for(var j = 0; j < size; j++){
                arr[random_line+j][random_column] = 1;
            }
            step++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

This may be a simple issue but I just can't figure out what's happening! Any help would be great!

Thanks,
mikeysantana

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at the browser's console? It normally tells you which record of the code is triggering the error (I personally enjoy Chome's debugging aids so I do recommend it).

Comment: It appears you are manipulating `arr`, and hence in next iteration, you are not finding index you are looking for..

Comment: Also note that errors tell you which line in code which is not mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You `random_line` variable in cases such as `arr[((random_line) + k)][random_column]` gets values larger than length-1 of your array `arr` so you are doing `undefined[random_column]`.

For every random_line variable you see in there you need to make sure they do not exceed the array's lastIndex, I did one line:

```
...else if (arr[Math.min((random_line) + k,DIM-1)][random_column] === 0 && arr[((random_line) + k)][((random_column) + 1)] === 0 && arr[((random_line) + k)][((random_column) - 1)] === 0 && arr[((random_line) + 1 + k)][random_column] === 0 && arr[((random_line) - 1 + k)][random_column] === 0){....
```

Make sure it is coherent with your game logic. In certain cases the size of the battleship is too large to fit to your grid especially when your random variable is towards the near of the array but you have a large ship to fit in.

Comment: Hello @ibowankenobi! Thanks for your help! I've done that for the if and else if conditions but it still gives me the error. Should it be done for columns and lines? I have gone ahead and change my question with the current code.

Comment: Yes unfortunately you will have to do it there as well. But this will impact your game logic, because let's say your grid size is 10, you choose row 9 , and then column 7 and then try to horizontally fit a ship size of 5 which will extend over your grid. So you need to check the before 2 columns and see if it is empty and then shift the ship backwards 2 columns. So the question you ask about the error is in fact about your game logic